# Binding on a not (yet) initialized livedata element

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

maybe the headline does not fit the question really well so I'll explain it.

In my app I send a request to a server to get gerneral user information. If I receive on I want to save it into the local room db. Now we come to the problem. I want to bind this one user to the view directly out of the db. But I can not bind a element, which maybe does not exists, because the request is in progress.

(My bad solution): Creating another livedate element which holds a boolean. I create a observer in the Activity and add the observer after the boolean observes a "true". With this solution I can not use "Data Binding" in the xml layout.

Does anyone have an idea? (If you need further information just ask - I know it is a really abstract question without any code)

Comment: *"But I can not bind a element, which maybe does not exists, because the request is in progress."* You bind `LiveData`, not the element of `LiveData`. `LiveData` can be bound without holding any element. You should instantiate a `LiveData` first, bind the xml to it, then request to the server.

Comment: @SanlokLee But the Dao returns a LiveData Element ... That's the case

Comment: You can query database and get that `LiveData` instance before db is populated with the actual data. That `LiveData` will be automatically updated once you save the data later. If this is not feasible, you can first instantiate an `MediatorLiveData` and bind view to it, then later you can add `LiveData` from dao as a source. You can also choose to use `Transformations#switchMap`.

Comment: And what happens with the observer which I already have added to the mediator LiveData? I have to assign a new one and that would be problematically

Comment: The observer will keep listening to the `MediatorLiveData`. You don't have to assign a new one at all. That would defeat the whole purpose of having `LiveData`.

Comment: So to have a clear answer: I can use get the user like: `var user: LiveData<User> = MutableLiveData()` no I assign a observer and later `user = dao.getUserById(1)` and the old server still reacts on a value change of the new user value?  But it is a new reference so how could that work?

Comment: That's not how it works. If you reassign `user` then it becomes a completely different instance and the observer will not listen to the new `LiveData`. Instead you can do `val user: MediatorLiveData<User>` and later you can call `user.addSource(dao.getUserById(1), ...)`.

Comment: Thank you :D now I understand what you mean. I was already searching for a method like `addSource(..)`. So that is the Solution  :) if you write a answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sanlok Lee mentioned:

> If you reassign `user` then it becomes a completely different instance and the observer will not listen to the new `LiveData`. Instead you can do `val user: MediatorLiveData<User>` and later you can call `user.addSource(dao.getUserById(1), ...)`

OR: 
Just load the user (also if you know that there is no one in the DB) from the DB. You can do that in you UserRepository for example.

```
val user: LiveData<User> = userDao.getUser()
```

The Livedata will get notified when there is a valid user inserted.